# How do I discard unprocessed event messages in a Delphi application?

Tags: delphi

I'm showing a "Please wait" form while performing some HTTP requests in a Delphi application. The "Please wait" dialog calls `Application.ProcessMessages` when it's closed.

This seems to have some undesirable consequences. For example if the user clicks on buttons in the form behind the "Please wait" dialog, those clicks seem to be added to the event queue and handled when `Application.ProcessMessages` is executed, even if the buttons are disabled before showing the dialog and enabled again after hiding it.

So I am wondering if there is any way to totally ignore mouse click events for the entire application while showing the "Please wait" dialog? I found that I can set `Enabled` of an entire form to `False` to prevent mouse click events  on that specific form, but other forms will still receive mouse click events when `Application.ProcessMessages` gets executed.

Is there any standard way of doing this? Either something like (hypothetical pseudo code) *`Application.Enabled := FALSE`* or *`Application.DiscardMessages`*?

Modifying the behaviour of the "Please wait" dialog (removing the call to `Application.ProcessMessages`) is out of my control - it's a standard company-wide dialog used in various places.

Comment: For the benefit of other readers: Don't use `Application.ProcessMessages`. The right solution is to have the slow task done in a separate thread. Now that I've said that, let's focus on your particular issue. One application design approach that I personally am very fond of is to use a `TActionList` for all actions in the application (accessed using any combination of menus, toolbar buttons, hotkeys, or pushbuttons). If you are using such a design, you only need to disable the action list.

Comment: You obviously don't want to stop responding to messages completely, because that would make your application unresponsive, impossible to move/resize, and it would also make the **Abort** button which I am sure you have in the "Please wait" dialog stop working.

Comment: Is your Dialog window a modal window?

Comment: Sounds like your real problem isn't what you think it is. Your real problem would appear to be that you aren't using a proper modal dialog, one that disables other top level windows.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm showing a "Please wait" form while performing some HTTP requests in a Delphi application. The "Please wait" dialog calls Application.ProcessMessages when it's closed.

It should not be doing that. That is a good indication that a bad design is being used.

The correct way to approach this is to perform the HTTP request in a worker thread, and display the dialog *modally* while the thread is busy doing its work, allowing the main message queue to still process messages normally. A modal dialog blocks user input from reaching windows outside of the dialog. When the thread is finished, the dialog can be closed, restoring user input to other windows.

> This seems to have some undesirable consequences. For example if the user clicks on buttons in the form behind the "Please wait" dialog, those clicks seem to be added to the event queue and handled when Application.ProcessMessages is executed, even if the buttons are disabled before showing the dialog and enabled again after hiding it.

That means the dialog is not processing any messages at all while it is being displayed. That is the wrong design for any dialog.

> So I am wondering if there is any way to totally ignore mouse click events for the entire application while showing the "Please wait" dialog?

Yes - process the messages normally while the dialog is running, just don't do anything with them. If your dialog were being shown *modally*, you would have gotten this behavior *for free*, as a modal dialog runs its own message loop, and disables other active windows, preventing any user input from reaching them.

> I found that I can set Enabled of an entire form to False to prevent mouse click events on that specific form, but other forms will still receive mouse click events when Application.ProcessMessages gets executed.

All the more reason to suspect that you are not using the dialog *modally*, as it would have disabled *all* of the windows in the calling thread for you.

> Is there any standard way of doing this?

Yes - fix your design. Use modal dialogs properly.

> Either something like (hypothetical pseudo code) Application.Enabled := FALSE or Application.DiscardMessages?

There is nothing like that in the VCL or FMX frameworks.  If you really need something like that, you would have to call the Win32 `PeekMessage()` function directly (on Windows only, of course), eg:

```pascal
procedure DiscardMouseClicks;
var
  msg: TMsg;
begin
  while PeekMessage(0, msg, MOUSE_FIRST, MOUSE_LAST, PM_REMOVE) do;
end;
```

Needless to say, if you have to resort to this, you are doing something wrong.

> Modifying the behaviour of the "Please wait" dialog (removing the call to Application.ProcessMessages) is out of my control - it's a standard company-wide dialog used in various places.

Then either your company is enforcing a bad design in all of its apps, or you are simply misusing the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your "Please wait" dialog is not modal, because a modal dialog *would* block user input outside the dialog for the duration of its lifetime. Furthermore, it would also/even process relevant or necessary window and application messages because it internally already *does* make use of `Application.ProcessMessages` and there would be no need to call it manually afterwards. This all is by design and free to use.

A dialog is made modal by showing it with the `ShowModal` method.

Since your current dialog is fixed (it is understood that it cannot be modified), then a solution could be to create a new separate modal dialog and to present your "Please wait" dialog on top of that.